# ¿como mostrar los registro duplicados de una base pero solo los que tengan la fecha más antigua en sql?

Tags: sql, base-de-datos, select, ms-access

```
SELECT * FROM [BASE NUEVA]
WHERE CONCATENAR In (SELECT CONCATENAR  FROM [BASE NUEVA] GROUP BY CONCATENAR HAVING  COUNT(*)>1)
ORDER BY CONCATENAR;
```

hasta el momento ya puede sacar los duplicados, pero quiero que solo se muestre los que tengan la fecha de registro más antigua que lo guarda la columna FECHREG

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Por un lado restringimos el resultado para que solo nos saque el valor mínimo de la fecha (fecha más antigua)

```
SELECT CONCATENAR, MIN(FECHREG) As FECHAMIN
FROM [BASE NUEVA] 
GROUP BY CONCATENAR 
HAVING  COUNT(*)>1
```

Ahora hacemos la consulta general haciendo un `JOIN` con estaprimera, y así restringimos los registros

```
SELECT a.* 
FROM [BASE NUEVA] a
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT CONCATENAR, MIN(FECHREG) As FECHAMIN
    FROM [BASE NUEVA] 
    GROUP BY CONCATENAR 
    HAVING  COUNT(*)>1
) b on a.CONCATENAR = b.CONCATENAR AND a.FECHREG = b.FECHAMIN
```